# I am travelling to the US but my ESTA is not updated, I moved to another country, should I apply again?

Tags: usa, esta

I have an ESTA authorization from last year, but since then I moved to another country. I am traveling to the USA for the holidays.

Should I use the same ESTA or apply for a new one?

Comment: @pnuts YOu can only update the address you'll be staying at whole in the US

Comment: When you moved to another country, did your nationality stay the same? Ie are you a citizen of Country A now living in Country B, or are you a former citizen of Country A who now lives in Country B and is now a citizen of Country B? Or dual nationality?

Answer (score 4):

The [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization) Website states:

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes

It doesn't list your home address; therefore you can use your current ESTA to travel to the US.

If they ask you about your place of residence, simply explain that you moved after obtaining the ESTA

Comment: @pnuts Of course not, that's the very thing that you can update in a current ESTA

Comment: @pnuts OP's home address, not address while staying in the US, changed. However, the home address cannot be updated, but nor does it have to

Comment: @pnuts OP did not imply that the address while in the US cannot be updated - they simply wonder about the home address. "my ESTA is not updated, I moved to another country" has nothing to do with the address while in the US, nor has OP suggested that the latter cannot be updated

Comment: I moved from Brazil to Sweden. On my ESTA it still says that i live in Brazil - that's why it's not uppdated.

Comment: I already updated the adress that i am going to the USA. But I am afraid they will give me a hard time.

Comment: @AnnaGarcia No, like I said, you will be fine. If they ask, just explain